# How to get the app I'm developing to send me a notification to remind me for an event?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm making a student organizer app, where I have a module to register the student for an event. Once it has been registered, I want the app to send a notification 10 minutes before the event. How do I proceed with this, since I have no knowledge about it?
P.S., I know I'll have to use flutter-local-notifications, but I don't know how to do it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `flutter_local_notifications`, you need to use [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging).

1. Install the package according to instructions.
2. Subscribe your users to topics whose names ( topics' names ) will be associated with the name of event so users will receive notifications for that event.
3. You may push notifications from  [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/) -> Clod messaging.
   Here you will create new notification and configure it.